# JDatabase Like Operator

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, jdatabase

I would like to know how to perform pattern search using JDatabase

Here's my code:

```
$query->select('Common_name');
$query->from($db->quoteName('common_name'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('Common_name').' LIKE '. $db->quote('\'o%\''));
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

Comment: The Joomla Documentation recommends using the 2nd parameter on both `quote()` and `escape()` when escape is nested inside of quote.  This is to avoid performing double escaping. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22712/12352

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
  ->select('Common_name')
  ->from($db->qn('your_table_name'))
  ->where($db->qn('Common_name').' LIKE '. $db->quote($db->escape('o%')));

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList(); // use loadResult() for single value result
```

Documentation is your best friend:
https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Comment: it produced an error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE LIKE' at line 3 SQL=SELECT Common_name FROM WHERE LIKE

Comment: It works fine to me. I added the $db, $query initialization code also above, please check.

Comment: actually it still has the same error even if i already initialized the $db and $query

Comment: can you post what is the code you write for `->from($db->qn('your_table_name'))`

Comment: ->from($db->qouteName('common_name'))

Comment: typo in that. it is quoteName not qouteName. Use shortcut `qn` if you want.

Comment: it worked perfectly now. thanks. i didn't notice that you put $results instead of result. thank you very much Nagarjun